# Adding quick explosion modifier adds transparency to objects created with duplicate linked in Blender 2.9.3

Tags: modifiers, transparency

I'm using Blender 2.9.3 and after adding a quick explode modifier to an object created with duplicate linked it added some transparency to it. At first I didnt notice because it wasnt full transparency, but when I added another quick explode modifier to an object of the same type, they became full transparent. I'm working it around by recreating the objects with duplicate object, but I have several objects created like this and I was wondering if there wasnt another solution. Is there another way to fix this?